# NLog does not work outside MainForm class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, nlog

I have this code

```
public partial class MainForm : Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadForm
{
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Main");

    private MyClass=new MyClass();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetupFormLogger();
        logger.Info(Properties.LogMessages.AppStarted); // this message appears in the richtextbox log
    }

    public void SetupFormLogger()
    {            
        NLog.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxTarget target = new NLog.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxTarget();
        target.Name = "control"; 
        target.Layout = "${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true} ${logger} ${message}";
        target.ControlName = richtextLog.Name;
        target.FormName = this.Name;
        target.TargetForm = this;
        target.AutoScroll = true;
        target.MaxLines = 10000;
        target.UseDefaultRowColoringRules = false;
        target.RowColoringRules.Add(
            new RichTextBoxRowColoringRule(
                "level == LogLevel.Trace", // condition
                "WhiteSmoke", // font color
                "Black", // background color
                FontStyle.Regular
            )
        );
        target.RowColoringRules.Add(new RichTextBoxRowColoringRule("level == LogLevel.Debug", "Gray", "Black"));
        target.RowColoringRules.Add(new RichTextBoxRowColoringRule("level == LogLevel.Info", "WhiteSmoke", "Black"));
        target.RowColoringRules.Add(new RichTextBoxRowColoringRule("level == LogLevel.Warn", "DarkRed", "Black"));
        target.RowColoringRules.Add(new RichTextBoxRowColoringRule("level == LogLevel.Error", "White", "DarkRed", FontStyle.Bold));
        target.RowColoringRules.Add(new RichTextBoxRowColoringRule("level == LogLevel.Fatal", "Yellow", "DarkRed", FontStyle.Bold));

        AsyncTargetWrapper asyncWrapper = new AsyncTargetWrapper();
        asyncWrapper.Name = "AsyncRichTextBox";
        asyncWrapper.WrappedTarget = target;

        SimpleConfigurator.ConfigureForTargetLogging(asyncWrapper, LogLevel.Debug);
    }
}
```

---

```
class MyClass
{
   public void Test()
   {
       Logger log=LogManager.GetLogger("MyClass");
       log.Info("Text");  // THIS TEXT IS NOT LOGGED OR DISPLAYED IN RICHTEXTBOX
   }
}
```

Comment: `SetupFormLogger` is called after `LogManager.GetLogger("Main")`. Just make the logger non-static and create the logger after `SetupFormLogger`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the order is important. MyClass is created before you setup your logging target. I think there is a function like `ReconfigureExistingLoggers` or something like that... Call it after creating the logging target or move up the call of the setup function and move the MyClass creation to FormLoad...

EDIT:
Just using ReconfigureExistingLoggers wont help since MyClass gots created before and so the logging message is sent before there is any LoggingTarget.

EDIT2: Where do you call `MyClass.Test`?

EDIT3: I dont know whats wrong on your side, I just copied your code to an empty form, added a RichTextBox and a Button, slightly modified your code  (content of the log message, not hardcoded the logger names) to this and it works. I'm using NLog 4.4.12 and NLog.Windows.Forms 4.2.3

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Main).Name);

    private MyClass instance =new MyClass();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetupFormLogger();
        logger.Info("Some message"); // this message appears in the richtextbox log
    }

    public void SetupFormLogger()
    {
        NLog.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxTarget target = new NLog.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxTarget();
        target.Name = "control";
        target.Layout = "${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true} ${logger} ${message}";
        target.ControlName = richTextBox1.Name;
        target.FormName = this.Name;
        target.TargetForm = this;
        target.AutoScroll = true;
        target.MaxLines = 10000;
        target.UseDefaultRowColoringRules = false;
        target.RowColoringRules.Add(new RichTextBoxRowColoringRule("level == LogLevel.Trace", "WhiteSmoke", "Black", FontStyle.Regular));
        target.RowColoringRules.Add(new RichTextBoxRowColoringRule("level == LogLevel.Debug", "Gray", "Black"));
        target.RowColoringRules.Add(new RichTextBoxRowColoringRule("level == LogLevel.Info", "WhiteSmoke", "Black"));
        target.RowColoringRules.Add(new RichTextBoxRowColoringRule("level == LogLevel.Warn", "DarkRed", "Black"));
        target.RowColoringRules.Add(new RichTextBoxRowColoringRule("level == LogLevel.Error", "White", "DarkRed", FontStyle.Bold));
        target.RowColoringRules.Add(new RichTextBoxRowColoringRule("level == LogLevel.Fatal", "Yellow", "DarkRed", FontStyle.Bold));

        AsyncTargetWrapper asyncWrapper = new AsyncTargetWrapper();
        asyncWrapper.Name = "AsyncRichTextBox";
        asyncWrapper.WrappedTarget = target;

        SimpleConfigurator.ConfigureForTargetLogging(asyncWrapper, LogLevel.Debug);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        instance.Test();
    }
}
class MyClass
{
    public void Test()
    {
        Logger log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass).Name);
        log.Info("Text");  // THIS TEXT IS NOT LOGGED OR DISPLAYED IN RICHTEXTBOX
    }
}
```

Comment: I call MyClass.Test after some time when the user clicks a button

Comment: I have moved the MyClass creation in the MainForm Load after SetupFormLogger and now it works!